# Create a list with an other letter

Tags: paralist

Is there a way to start the list (using compactenum) with the letter b) instead of a) without any definition in the preamble?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}
\begin{compactenum}[a)] 
\item one % start with b)
\item two
\item three
\end{compactenum}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}
\begin{compactenum}[a)]\setcounter{enumi}{1}
\item one % start with b)
\item two
\item three
\end{compactenum}
\end{document}
```

[image]